# Can we map oracle table to collections in Mongo using Mongo?

Tags: oracle, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java, morphia

We have a project running in Oracle/ Sql. I am trying to create an extension using mongoDB. Can I map my pojo collections in extension to the tables in my original project.
I have read mapping two collections but have never read about mapping tables to collections (one to many, or many to one etc). Original project is too complex to run on mongoDB, or it may take years to transition from Oracle/Sql to mongo.

I tried not mapping the fields which needs mapping to the org project tables but got error as :

```
org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Error mapping field:*.machine

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: *.machine.*.materials, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```